# Create bar chart in PowerBI by aggregating on string values

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am new to PowerBI and I need to create 2 visualization(bar chart) which will show the following:

Chart1--- 3 bars for each of the tag strings(alpha, beta, gama) and the count of customers for each tag string(alpha=5, beta=4, gama=4).

Chart2 --- 3 bars for each of the tag strings(alpha, beta, gama) and the total of value for each tag string(alpha=160, beta=90, gama=100).

Please, help me with how to get this two charts with tutorial. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Power Query Editor" perform this following steps-

> ***Its better to use a separate table for this. So at the beginning, you can duplicate your table with a new name. This way the change in data will not impact other presentation in the report if you already have.***

**Step-1:** Duplicate your column "tags" and automatically the new column name will be - "tags - copy"

**Step-2:** Apply "Split Column by Delimiter" on  your new column "tags - copy" using value "Comma". No you have 3 new columns "tags - copy.1", "tags - copy.2" & "tags - copy.3".

**Step-3:** Select your original three column "customer", "tags" and "value" and select the "Unpivot Other Columns" from the "Transform" bar on top as shown in the below image-

[image]

**Step-4:** Remove the column with name "Attribute".

**Step-5:** Finally you have a table as below and you can now generate your both chart easily form this data. Just use new column value.1 for your dimension value to present in the chart.

[image]

Here below is the sample output you can get in Power BI from the above data-

[image]